# What happens to the old one after swapping with an unnamed object in C++

Tags: c++, stl

Consider the statement `decltype(s){}.swap(s)`, where `s` is a STL class entity. If `s` is not `::std::array`, this gets a nice complexity ( O(constant) ).

But I wonder, where the **old** one goes? Is it automatically deleted?

I think so, for the old one will never be used again. But I'm not sure about that (if the compiler will think so).

Comment: I may have messed up the tagging. By stl do you mean a C++ Standard Library container class or do you literally mean the old Standard Template Library?

Comment: I did mean Standard Template Library, for the statement mentioned could be used in STL classes widely. But if you like, to remove it is of no importance.

Comment: OK. My apologies for jumping the gun. Should have asked first. I'll put the stl tag back.

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen anyone use Stepanov/Musser/Lee HP's STL for over 23 years.  Does it even work with a modern C++ compiler?

Comment: The nice thing about C++ is that you always know when objects are going to be destroyed. Its nice logical and easy to reason about. So yes the temporary object you created with `decltype(s){}` will be destroyed when it goes out of scope. Scoped depends where it is used. But if this was a simple statement, then you can think of it as the `;` at the end of the logical line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *content* of `s` is swapped with the *content* of the temporary object created by `decltype(s){}`.  Effectively, `s` will simply become re-initialized with its default content, and the temporary object will destroy the old content when itself is destroyed when it goes out of scope.

And FYI, `swap()` works with `std::array`, too.

Comment: thx anyway, for your wonderful answer. However I'd like to say, swapping `std::array` costs O(linear) time while other stl classes use only O(constant). So I never do swap `std::array`. 